# how to get mono develop xsp2 accessible from my lan?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, xsp2

I am writing an asp.net mvc project on my ubuntu laptop. I want to be able to see how the website looks on my mac and winndows boxes. How can I get monodevelop to start xsp2 so that it listens on an external IP?

My ufw firewall is off. I have looked in `man xsp2`, I can see you can set the IP to listen on but can't see how you get monodevelop to launch it with different options.

**Edit:** I want to get monodevelop to start xsp2 (i.e. when I hit f5/ctrl+f5 for debugging) so it listens externally (I know how to launch it on it's own).

I did a `ps -aux` and found monodevelop launches xsp2 like this:

```
/usr/bin/mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:35479 /usr/lib/mono/2.0/xsp2.exe --port 8080 --address 127.0.0.1 --nonstop --verbose
```

I need to get monodevelop to launch xsp2 with `--address 0.0.0.0` but how?

**Edit 2**: Running this with my project dir as my current directory works fine:

```
/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/2.0/xsp2.exe --port 8080 --address 0.0.0.0  --nonstop
```

Which is ok, but I don't get the useful debugging stuff because I am running it outside of monodevelop.

I have now tried editing my web.config to add the following:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MonoServerAddress" value="0.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>
```

... which does not work. Monodevelop still launches xsp2 with 127.0.0.1 on the command line, which I take it is overriding the value in the web.config. This is the same whether I debug (f5) or run (ctrl f5).

Is it possible to get monodevelop to start xsp2 with a different --address?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't get the useful debugging stuff

It is good programming practice regardless of language being used, to run erroneous code through a debugger or the provided debugging flag (many languages provide you with a flag(parameter) that you specify whilst running the code to view potential problem points in your code.

For Mono, use the following  command line parameters:
`--debug`, `--debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:35479`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows/Visual Studio, the program that creates the asp.net aware web server is "webdev.exe".

The equivalent for Ubuntu/Mono should be "xsp2":

http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Mono_equivalents_to_.NET

You need to:

1) Make sure your firewall is open to your xsp2 port (typically *not* port 80!)

2) Make sure your LAN can resolve Ubuntu's hostname (or connect to ubuntu by ipv4 address)

3) Are you using this syntax?

```
   mono mod-mono-server.exe [options]
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/xsp2.1.html

4) You can configure your settings (e.g. port#, protocol, etc) from the command line (as the above man page) or in AppSettings.

Comment: as I said, my firewall is off. Yes I am connecting to the correct IP and port number (8080), and I have connectivity form my mac/windows boxes to my laptop. I've edited my question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Q: You say you "know how to launch it on it's own".  Does this mean you've successfully bound to IN_ANY (0.0.0.0), and that you've successfully connected from external clients when you launched it manually?  What syntax did you use?  Q: Otherwise, did you try any of the available command-line options and/or AppSettings file settings?

Comment: Running it manually is fine (edit 2 above). Good point on the appsettings. Somehow missed that when I first looked at the man page. Unfortunately, it seems to have no effect setting MonoServerAddress as described above.I'm starting to think this may be a limitation of the monodevelop asp.net debugging environment.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Have you tried going in the project options> Run> XSP Web Server> IP Address and put the IP of the computer running MonoDevelop? Like 192.168.1.x